# Octave plotting with FLTK: Subplots getting smaller and smaller..?

Tags: matlab, octave, fltk

I'm using Octave 3.8.1.

Consider the following code:

```
I=4;
J=6;
for j=1:J
    for i=1:I
        g=subplot(I,J,(i-1)*J+j);
        imagesc(rand(20,20));
    end
end
```

This produces the following plot:
[image: strangely sized subplots]

Why aren't the subplots equally sized?
What do I need to do to get them equally sized?

I'm using the default FLTK module for plotting.

Comment: Woah... that is so weird.  That shouldn't be happening at all.  I tried reconstructing on my end.  I'm on Octave 3.8.1 and this is what I get with your code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0DjzQ.png .  Try using `imshow` perhaps?

Comment: Tried `imshow`, same results, problem remains (except for the plots are not colored of course)

Comment: From the ArchLinux documentation: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Octave - it says FLTK has some serious instability issues.  Try changing your default plotting system to `gnuplot` instead.  Do this in the command prompt: `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");`

Comment: The problem is, gnuplot has other issues. But in case this is a bug, I will stick to it for the moment. Thanks.

Comment: You may have to switch back and forth depending on what you want to show.  Did switching the graphics system work?  Also, mind if I write an answer?

Comment: Yes, it solved *this* isse ;) Sure, write one, I will accept it.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7?

Comment: @user3353819 No, Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 to be precisely.

Comment: @theV0ID Ah nm. I was wondering if it might have been related to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/_QUBkFsbQnQ which is to do with a bug regarding miscalculating window borders which has the side effect of windows appearing too small. Probably unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing my comments as an answer for those experiencing similar problems.

From the ArchLinux documentation: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Octave - it says FLTK has some serious instability issues. Try changing your default plotting system to `gnuplot` instead.

Do this in the command prompt: `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");`

FWIW, I actually reconstructed your figure using FLTK on my end, and this is what I get:

[image]

---

So weird!... but the weirdness of FLTK may be platform dependent.  I'm on Mac OS, so that may contribute why I'm not getting any weird results.

Glad to have helped!